# Call function from another js file when using iife pattern?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, iife

Is it possible to call function that is in one js file and it is made public by usage of iife pattern, in another js file?
For example, this is some validationScript.js file:

```
var ValidationNamespace = function () 
{
    var nameValidation = "";
    var testValidation = "";

    return{
        validateIfNameAlreadyExistsInTable : function(currentNameValues)
        {
            for(var i=0; i < currentNameValues.length ; i++)
            {
                if(document.getElementById("tbName").value == currentNameValues[i])
                {
                    var nameVal = "Name already exists in table!";
                    document.getElementById("nameVal").innerHTML = nameVal;
                    return false;
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("nameVal").innerHTML = "";
            return true;
        }
   };
}();
```

And I have another file, lets say script.js

Is there some way to call function `validateIfNameAlreadyExistsInTable` from some script.js function?

The problem is that it is undefined when I try to call it:

[image]

I have index.html where I am referencing both .js files like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="validationScript.js"></script>
```

Comment: `ValidationNamespace` is holding `object` returned.. Use `ValidationNamespace.validateIfNameAlreadyExistsInTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because the IIFE returned an object that exposes the function, and the file saves that object as `ValidationNamespace`, which is a `var` declared globally and thus a global variable.

So:

```
ValidationNamespace.validateIfNameAlreadyExistsInTable(theName);
```

Re your edit, you probably want to load the scripts in the other order, first `validationScript.js` then `script.js`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="validationScript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Scripts are loaded and run in the order you give them (unless you use `async` or `defer`). So unless your code in `script.js` is waiting for some other event, it'll run before `validationScript.js` is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for answering I did that I and I one error, saying that ValidationNamespace doesn't exists. I will update my question with additional information. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @nemo_87: You need to do this *after* the other script has been loaded. Other than that, it's guaranteed to work unless something is assigning a different value to that variable (or the property) later.

Comment: Oooh so I see, I have to first load validationScript and than script.js. That make sense! Thank you :) @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.
ValidationNamespace().validateIfNameAlreadyExistsInTable(theName);

Comment: `ValidationNamespace` is not a function, so trying to call it will cause an error.